# How to remove section titles from CoreDataBooks example?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

I am having troubles with errors popping up or the wrong result. I have based taken the structure of CoreData usage in Apple's CoreDataBooks example and want to remove the usage of section titles and just have a flat out list.

I am particularly interested in an explanation of what is changing to achieve my requirements to help me learn what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this very easily. Just comment out `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` and the titles will be removed from your table view.

Comment: You may also want to set the `NSFetchedResultsController init...sectionNameKeyPath:` argument to nil.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I tell you where I was going wrong. I was removing/changing numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection thinking they would effect one another.

Comment: Both those delegate methods are essential for a working table view